# Ошибка при компиляции, Си

Tags: c, компиляция

Не получается скомпилировать данный код.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file =  fopen("c:\test.txt", "w");
    int wordNumbers;
    printf("please add an amount of words into the dictionary ");
    scanf("%i", &wordNumbers);

    for (int i=0; i< wordNumbers; i++)
    {
        char word[30] = {0};
        printf("add a word into the dictionary please\n");
        scanf("%s", &word);
        fprintf(file, "%s", word);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Указывает на ошибки в строке

```
for (int i=0; i< wordNumbers; i++)
```

Пишет: "синтаксическая ошибка", и о не объявлении переменной `і`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где здесь ошибка. Сама программа, по идее, должна в файл записывать некоторые слова, которые в последующем я использую в качестве словаря.

Comment: Какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: вполне себе компилируется gcc6.3

Comment: пишу на visual studio 10. компилирую там же

Comment: @AltynbekTanbayev. Добавьте в вопрос вывод компилятора с ошибками

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Возможно ваш компилятор не поддерживает стандарт C99 и требует, чтобы все переменные были объявлены в начале блока.

Поэтому объявите переменную `i` в начале функции. Например,

```
int main()
{
    FILE *file =  fopen("c:\test.txt", "w");
    int wordNumbers;
    int i;
    ^^^^^ 
    printf("please add an amount of words into the dictionary ");
    scanf("%i", &wordNumbers);

    for ( i=0; i< wordNumbers; i++)
    {
        //...
```

Comment: Заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка скорее всего в том, что программа компилируется в режиме `C90` или в более ранних стандартах. Там действительно запрещено объявлять переменные таким образом. Пример:

```
int main( void )
{
  for( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {}
  return 0;
}
```

1)

```
$ gcc -ansi 1.c 
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:7:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
   for( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {}
   ^
1.c:7:3: note: use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code
```

2)

```
$ gcc -std=c90 1.c 
1.c: In function ‘main’:
1.c:7:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
   for( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {}
   ^
1.c:7:3: note: use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code
```

3)

```
$ gcc -std=c99 1.c && echo "$?"
0
```

В двух первых случаях C-код должен выглядеть так:

```
int main( void )
{
  int i;
  for( i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {}
  return 0;
}
```

Или меняйте стандарт в опциях компилятора/IDE.

P.S. А работа с файлами тут вообще не при чём. Поменяйте заголовок чтобы никого не сбивать с толку.

P.P.S. а, нет, при чём :) Но это уже совсем другой вопрос (подсказка: ошибка в `"c:\test.txt"`)

Comment: Учел, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @AltynbekTanbayev, см. P.P.S :-)

Comment: там двойной слеш должен быть да? спасибо)

Comment: Какой стандарт в M$ компиляторе? Там отродясь дальше C89 ничего не происходило практически.

Comment: @0andriy, в вопросе указана IDE, а не компилятор. Умеет ли студия  подхватывать другие комиляторы я не знаю (в качестве внешней утилиты - наверняка умеет). Но точно знаю, что майкрософтовский под Windows далеко не единственный.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958778/i-need-to-change-compiler-on-vs/14958847#14958847

Comment: @0andriy, о как... Ну, это не повод истреблять в человеке тягу к лучшему :)